# Building a new variable in R which depends on the value of another variable

Tags: r, variables, conditional-statements

I have to build a new variable (called: condition).
My data frame contains three distance variables: distance1.1, distance1.2, distance1.3
(depending on their condition, the test subjects always have values in only two of the three variables )

If there is no value (NA) in the variable "distance 1.1", the value of the new condition should be 1.

If there is no value (NA) in the variable "distance 1.2", the value of the new condition should be 2.

If there is no value (NA) in the variable "distance 1.3", the value of the new condition should be 3.

Can anyone help me, how I can build this new variable in R?

Comment: Wellcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use simple conditional structure, like that:

```
if (is.nan(distance1.1)) {
  condition <- 1
} else if (is.nan(distance1.2)) {
  condition <- 2
} else {
  condition <- 3
}

Have a nice day !
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data.frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  distance1.1 = c(NA, 2, 3, 4),
  distance1.2 = c(1, NA, 3, NA),
  distance1.3 = c(1, 2, NA, 4)
)
df

  distance1.1 distance1.2 distance1.3
1          NA           1           1
2           2          NA           2
3           3           3          NA
4           4          NA           4
```

You can use `apply` to rowwise identify which columns have missing `NA` values. You can use `sub` to extract the last digit of the column name to store in your new `condition` column.

```
df$condition <- apply(df, 1,
  function(x) sub('distance1.(\\d+)', '\\1', names(which(is.na(x))))
)
df

  distance1.1 distance1.2 distance1.3 condition
1          NA           1           1         1
2           2          NA           2         2
3           3           3          NA         3
4           4          NA           4         2
```

If you might have more than one missing value in a row, you can pursue other options in the `apply` function, depending on what you want `condition` to look like.